# RAILS 3.2 - Submit form posts "nil" variable using params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, post, parameters, null

I'm stuck on something that doesn't make sense!  I'm simply trying to submit a form with "comments" on a blog post.

Here is my form view:

```
<%= form_for @comment, :remote => true, :url => forumpost_comments_path(forumpost) do |s| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= s.label :content, "Write a comment" %>
        <%= s.text_area :content, :rows => "3" %>
     </div>
     <%= s.submit "Reply"%>
 <% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
def create
    @forumpost = Forumpost.find_by_id(params[:forumpost_id])
    @comment = @forumpost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to search_static_pages_path
     else
      redirect_to search_static_pages_path
     end
  end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :content
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :forumpost

   validates :user_id, presence: true
   validates :forumpost_id, presence: true
end
```

And here are my logs:

```
Started POST "/forumposts/331/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-14 11:41:24 -0800
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3w3WACRYA6JEwvIg9C66k+cR1ZdRSWwA5Z+W0et1sS8=",
 "forumpost"=>{"content"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Reply", "forumpost_id"=>"331"}

(0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("content", "created_at", "forumpost_id", "updated_at", "user_id") 
    VALUES     (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", nil], ["created_at", Sat, 14 Dec 2013 18:58:58 UTC +00:00], 
    ["forumpost_id", 331],     ["updated_at", Sat, 14 Dec 2013 18:58:58 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]

   (14.3ms)  commit transaction
```

As you can see, the content portion is nil even though I have filled out the content field and submitted it.

I would really appreciate any guidance on the matter!  Thanks!

Comment: can you add the full log message, mostly interested in the Parameters section

Comment: what is the @comment object in view? it should be instance of Comment model.

Comment: is content and actual field of Comment?

Comment: Hi house9.  I've added the parameters section.

Hi Naren, @comment object is a Comment model.  It appears that the parameters have "forumpost"=>{"content"=>"test"} instead of "comment"=>{"content"=>"test"}.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Looks like your comments is nested, so I imagine in your form_for you need to include something like form_for [@forumposts, @comments] or something along that line.

Comment: content is an attribute of both forumpost and comment.

Hi Shaun, that's a very interesting suggestion!  However, making that change we still have "forumpost"=>{"content"=>"test"} instead of "comment"=>{"content"=>"test"}.

Comment: Hey everyone! Thanks for your suggestions.

The solution was the change @comment to :comment in the form_for.  I have no idea why.  It would be nice if someone explained.  lol

     <%= form_for :comment, :remote => true, :url => forumpost_comments_path(forumpost) do |f| %>
             <div class="field">
                  <%= f.label :content, "Reply" %>
                  <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => "3" %>
              </div>
              <%= f.submit "Reply"%>
            <% end %>

Comment: Can you show the controller code for the `new` action that loads the form?